# SerialPort data stacking and when ı send request executing previous request

Tags: c#, serial-port, flush

Im using serial port for communication with device. But when ı cancel process and send new its executing previous process.

```
            serialPort.BaudRate = baudrate;
            serialPort.PortName = portname;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 120000;
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            serialPort.Open();
```

Send Request :

```
 public void sendRequest(byte[] data)
    {
        if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort.Open();

        }
        serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);  

        serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
       
    }
```

Here is my receive handler
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

```
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;

        int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
 
        if (port.BytesToRead > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("reading");
            port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            setResultMessage(buffer);
            getParsedData();
            printDebug();          
        }      
    }
```

Comment: The data is not being flushed.  You problem may not be on the transmit side but on the receive side.  The is why it is always important on receive code to make robust to align data and look for a start character instead of just assuming the first character is what sent.

Comment: Can you explain your answer with examples.  Editted my question for my received data logic. What should ı do in that func?

Comment: Make sure on the receive side you are checking for a valid start message.  If you do not have a valid start than throw away the data before you get the valid start character.  This is what ALIGNING means when receiving data.

Comment: What do you mean throw away the data before you get the valid start character. With discardinbuffer and discardoutbuffer?

Comment: I do not know anything about the protocol that is being used.  A connection has a transport layer and an application layer.  The cancel is done at the application layer.  The cancel may not be able to flush data from the transport layer or from the hardware.  That is why it is important to design Application Layer software to be robust. A that is why most standard protocols use a start character and end character in the protocol to be ROBUST.  You protocol should send a START character at beginning of every message and the receive code should check for the start character.

Comment: Im sending same data which generated by my code, with docklight. That problem not appearing ı checked datas fully same. Docklight also dont know anything about my beginnig character, how docklight handling with this issue?

Comment: When sending with Docklight send one message, then wait for response and send 2nd message.  If Docklight works then there is probably a wait time between messages or you are not waiting for a response in your code before sending second message.

Comment: What's the problem after all? The title and a few sentences seem to lack an explanation of what the problem is in what situation. By the way, in terms of source code, shouldn't it be necessary to register the DataReceivedEventHandler only once immediately after the first Open()? Registering immediately after each Write() seems to increase the likelihood of a problem.